# Parsing IDA Pro .asm files

Tags: disassembly, ida

Does anyone know of projects that parse the disassembly from IDA Pro using a lexer and/or parser generator library? But I would also totally be fine with JSON or XML format. So far, I have been able to produce HTML from the GUI, but I am looking for a command line tool that will parse disassembly files produced by IDA Pro.

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What are you *actually* trying to do?

Comment: I am moving to IDA Pro disassembly in order to do my own static analysis. I had used Distorm in the past, but I want to experiment with IDA Pro. I am parsing asm files produced by IDA Pro disassembler to interface with an IR translator. It's that not that big of a deal I just do not want to reinvent the wheel here. What's a XY problem?

Comment: I am _actually_ trying to do this: "First, the binary file is disassembled. toil currently interfaces with two disassemblers: IDA Pro, a commercial disassembler, and a linear sweep disassembler built on top of GNU libopcodes.  Interfacing with other disassemblers is straight-forward." (Very old BAP documentation).

Comment: You're going at it backwards. Instead of parsing assembler text, you should use IDA scripting or native APIs to get the instructions in nice, broken down representation.

Comment: I am all ears if I can get a better representation. Are you suggesting using GetDisasm? What do you mean by broken down representation? Can you please point me to the right documentation? Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar question or requirement asked by @turnersr. Is there any existing project that parses the disassembly file produced by the objdump or IDA pro using the lexer and parser library/tool or published project?

Comment: Welcome to RE.SE. If you have a different query that is not answered here then please ask a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd be better off using IDC functions like [GetMnem()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/274.shtml), [GetOpType()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/276.shtml), [GetOperandValue()](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/277.shtml), etc. to extract IDA's disassembly than exporting to JSON/XML.

You can use [command-line switches](https://www.hex-rays.com/products/ida/support/idadoc/417.shtml) to run IDA in batch-mode with your IDC script to automate the entire process.

Comment: Thanks! I did not know you could do that in IDA Pro. This is differently the right approach for me.

Comment: I would recommend `DecodeInstruction()` which gives the most detail.