# Convert IDA listings to assembly without using IDA non-free

Tags: ida, disassembly, assembly

I'm currently working with a huge set of IDA Pro listings (`~1TiB`).

For a project I need to perform analyses on the `mnemonics` and `operands` on a subroutine level. Therefor I want to convert the IDA format in a plain assembly format, as the existing parser only works for "PLAIN ASM" files.

Additonally this should be done without using a non-free version of IDA.

**IDA ASM**

```
.text:00401000                             ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00401000
.text:00401000                             ; Attributes: bp-based frame
.text:00401000
.text:00401000                             sub_401000      proc near           ; CODE XREF: sub_43BD35+Ap
.text:00401000
.text:00401000                             var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
.text:00401000                             var_8           = dword ptr -8
.text:00401000                             var_4           = dword ptr -4
.text:00401000
.text:00401000 55                                  push    ebp
.text:00401001 8B EC                                   mov     ebp, esp
.text:00401003 83 EC 0C                                sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:00401006 89 4D F4                                mov     [ebp+var_C], ecx
.text:00401009 8B 45 F4                                mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:00401021 59                                  pop     ecx
.text:00401022
.text:00401022                             loc_401022:                 ; CODE XREF: sub_401000+Fj
.text:00401022 8B 45 F4                                mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:00401025 83 78 04 00                             cmp     dword ptr [eax+4], 0
.text:00401029 74 12                                   jz      short locret_40103D
.text:0040102B 8B 45 F4                                mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:0040102E 8B 40 04                                mov     eax, [eax+4]
.text:00401031 89 45 F8                                mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
.text:00401034 FF 75 F8                                push    [ebp+var_8]     ; void *
.text:00401037 E8 B8 0D 00 00                              call    ??3@YAXPAX@Z    ; operator delete(void *)
.text:0040103C 59                                  pop     ecx
.text:0040103D
.text:0040103D                             locret_40103D:                  ; CODE XREF: sub_401000+29j
.text:0040103D C9                                  leave
.text:0040103E C3                                  retn
.text:0040103E                             sub_401000      endp
```

Convert to:

**PLAIN ASM**

```
=============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
push    ebp
mov     ebp, esp
sub     esp, 0Ch
mov     [ebp+var_C], ecx
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
pop     ecx
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
cmp     dword ptr [eax+4], 0
jz      short locret_40103D
mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
mov     eax, [eax+4]
mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
push    [ebp+var_8]     ; void *
call    ??3@YAXPAX@Z    ; operator delete(void *)
pop     ecx
leave
retn
```

**Question:**
Are there solutions or scripts already existing for such a (automatically or batch-mode) conversion (at the best without needing a IDA non-free version)?

Comment: Your plain ASM removed the declarations for the stack variables. That's a bit too far on the "plain" side. Can't you not just cut off the first *n* characters, using just about any text manipulator?

Comment: Cutting of the declarations for the stack is not too bad. The plain ASM does not have to be valid in this sense (sorry for not mentioning this). Cutting of the first _n_ chars seems plausible. However, I am more concerned  about the inline comments, loc definitions etc.. Additionally I'm not very familiar with the IDA ASM format and worried to miss some special annotations, which will cause the parser to misinterpret the input. Hoped there is an existing and more "sophisticated" solution out there.

Comment: IDA's labels look like perfectly regular ones to me, and so does its comments: `;` is a common comment character in assembly. Are you sure your assembler has problems with these? Also, check the File > Output menu. From memory, it ought to have a separate `Export as ASM` entry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you already have the assembly output produced by ida and want to parse test only if that is the case you can improvise this.

Assuming i copy pasted the `IDA.ASM` in your post to a text file.

I can print all the disassembly lines only using the XXX below 
if you are on windows you need the gnuwin32 port of the unix utilities used in path.

---

**Suggestion 1:**

Details of the text file:

```
wc -l ida.asm & echo. & head -n 2 IDA.ASM & echo. & tail -n 2 IDA.ASM & echo. & head -n 11 IDA.ASM | tail -1
```

Output:

```
31 ida.asm

.text:00401000                             ; =============== S U B R O U T I N E =======================================
.text:00401000

.text:0040103E C3                                  retn
.text:0040103E                             sub_401000      endp
.text:00401000 55                                  push    ebp
```

Text parsing to isolate disassembly only from the said text file:

```
tac ida.asm | awk "{if(a[$1]++==0){print $0} }" | sort
```

Result as follows:

```
:\>tac ida.asm | awk "{if(a[$1]++==0){print $0} }" | sort
.text:00401000 55                                  push    ebp
.text:00401001 8B EC                                   mov     ebp, esp
.text:00401003 83 EC 0C                                sub     esp, 0Ch
.text:00401006 89 4D F4                                mov     [ebp+var_C], ecx
.text:00401009 8B 45 F4                                mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:00401021 59                                  pop     ecx
.text:00401022 8B 45 F4                                mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:00401025 83 78 04 00                             cmp     dword ptr [eax+4], 0
.text:00401029 74 12                                   jz      short locret_40103D
.text:0040102B 8B 45 F4                                mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
.text:0040102E 8B 40 04                                mov     eax, [eax+4]
.text:00401031 89 45 F8                                mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
.text:00401034 FF 75 F8                                push    [ebp+var_8]     ; void *
.text:00401037 E8 B8 0D 00 00                              call    ??3@YAXPAX@Z    ; operator delete(void *)
.text:0040103C 59                                  pop     ecx
.text:0040103D C9                                  leave
.text:0040103E                             sub_401000      endp.text:0040103E C3                                  retn
```

---

**Suggestion 2:**

Well as i commented if you could print the last line of a group based on first column comparison you can elieminate tac.
I searched around SO and found this [print last line in each group of result based on comparison results of  first column only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5429840/eliminate-duplicate-lines-and-keep-the-last-one) .

I adapted it to the needs of this question:

```
awk "{a[$1]=$0} END {for (i in a ) print a[i]}" IDA.lst  | sort | awk "{ print substr($0,42) }" | tr -s [:blank:]
```

Output:

```
 push ebp
 mov ebp, esp
 sub esp, 0Ch
 mov [ebp+var_C], ecx
 mov eax, [ebp+var_C]
 pop ecx
 mov eax, [ebp+var_C]
 cmp dword ptr [eax+4], 0
 jz short locret_40103D
 mov eax, [ebp+var_C]
 mov eax, [eax+4]
 mov [ebp+var_8], eax
 push [ebp+var_8] ; void *
 call ??3@YAXPAX@Z ; operator delete(void *)
 pop ecx
 leave
 sub_401000 endp
```

---

**Suggestion 3:**

A similar solution based on the suggestions above. This approach will additionally respects the last `retn` statement and filters out comments (`;`) at the end of the line:

```
grep -E "^.{10,15} [0-9A-F]{2} *" IDA.ASM | sort | cut -c40-200 | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d ";" -f1
```

Output:

```
 push ebp
 mov ebp, esp
 sub esp, 0Ch
 mov [ebp+var_C], ecx
 mov eax, [ebp+var_C]
 pop ecx
 mov eax, [ebp+var_C]
 cmp dword ptr [eax+4], 0
 jz short locret_40103D
 mov eax, [ebp+var_C]
 mov eax, [eax+4]
 mov [ebp+var_8], eax
 push [ebp+var_8]
 call ??3@YAXPAX@Z
 pop ecx
 leave
 retn
```

## Pure AWK Based Suggestion

I have an aversion to using n number of utilities to accomplish a job
and i needed to brush up my `awkyquotient` so here is an awk only code
you may need to test rinse and repeat
it seems to work for the copy paste of plain.asm

```
{ 
    a[$1] = $0 ;                      # array a will contain last  entry in each group 
    if(b[$1]++==0) c[$1] = $0;        # array c will contain first entry of each group
} END { 
    n = asort(a); m = asort(c);       # sort both arrays
    if (n == m) {                     # some caution    
        for( k=1; k<=n; k++ ){     
            if(a[k]!= c[k]) {         # lets split input into 3 seperate arrays  
                d[k] = a[k]           # one where all entries except last is valid
                e[k] = c[k]           # one where only last entry is valid
            } else {
                f[k] = a[k]           # one where both arrays have same entries
            }
        }
    }
    o = asort(d); p = asort(e) ; q= asort(f) # sort all 3 arrays
    z = 1;
    while(z != o)    {
        g[z] = d[z]                  #insert final array with first n entries 
        z++;                         #(except last entry)
    }
    y = 1;
    while(y != q+1) {
        g[z] = f[y]                  #insert final array with all equal entries 
        z++;y++
    }
    x = p;
    while(x != p-1) {
        g[z] = e[x]                  # insert final array with last entry
        z++;x--
    }
    r = asort(g)                     # sort the final array and print substring
    startofdis = 44;                 # lets set a start    
    for (i = 1; i <= r; i++ ) {
    match(g[i] ,/;.*/);              # match everything after a ; (semicolon)
    if(RLENGTH == -1){               # awk should set the RSTART and RLENGTH
    print substr( g[i] ,startofdis)  # if RLENGHT == -1 no semicolon 
    }                                # lets print from startofdis to end
    else
    print substr(g[i] , startofdis , RSTART-startofdis ) # print only the middle portion
    }
}
```

### Result as follows

```
:\>awk -f awky.txt ida.lst
        push    ebp
            mov     ebp, esp
            sub     esp, 0Ch
            mov     [ebp+var_C], ecx
            mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
        pop     ecx
            mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
            cmp     dword ptr [eax+4], 0
            jz      short locret_40103D
            mov     eax, [ebp+var_C]
            mov     eax, [eax+4]
            mov     [ebp+var_8], eax
            push    [ebp+var_8]
                call    ??3@YAXPAX@Z
        pop     ecx
        leave
        retn

:\>
```

Comment: Something like a `tac` based solution was my first intention too, with the knowledge that the last line of the file **always** contains the most recent information. Speaking for the last line of the _result_ output: Are there more cases where I have to concern about the situations where `.text:0040103E sub_401000` is the output instead of `.text:0040103E C3  retn`. A second filter cirteria could be a blank column right behind the address, right?

Comment: yes you should test the script and improvise it is a hack and not fool proof you should just tac the file first and iron out tac idiosyncracies prior to piping and you should iron out the awk wrinkles or settle for some compromises between perfect and absolutely crap results the last line is where the awk fails to print the last unique in group (if you could solve this you dont need tac in first place)

Comment: @knox well i updated my answer and eliminated the need for tac take a look

Comment: Okay that's awesome. Another suggestion to handle the problem of the missing last `retn` instruction: a regex that considers the first opcode column after the address column `grep -E "^.{10,15} [0-9A-F]{2} *" function.asm`

Comment: so a final approach could be: `grep -E "^.{10,15} [0-9A-F]{2} *" function.asm | sort | cut -c40-200 | tr -s [:blank:] | cut -d ";" -f1`

Comment: i added a pure awk only approach hope fully that should nail the list into asm

Answer (score 0):

The IDA database's representation of the binary code which sometimes takes a few liberties for the sake of analyzing the program logic.  One of those simplifications is the auto-creation of argument and local variable representation (arg_*, var_*) that you see.

If you want to get closer to a cleaner assembly representation, try [Capstone](http://www.capstone-engine.org).  If you identify the file offsets for the functions that you need to analyze using IDA (or some other disassembler), you can just feed those to Capstone to generate the disassembly.  Also, you can easily write an IDC script (IIRC, the free version of IDA doesn't come with IDAPython support) to dump out the instructions you need in binary form for each function you want to analyze, and pass that into Capstone to generate the disassembly.

Comment: iirc he already has someone produce an asm file from some version of idapro and wants to parse the text and remove the extra ida specific whatever and just keep the disassembly alone if i am not wrong

Comment: @blabb is totally correct

Comment: Good to know, might want to edit the original question though. "I currently only own a free version of IDA" and "at best without using an IDA non-free version" implies that you're working with an .idb file and not text.  It would be less confusing to say you're working with text output from IDA's disassembly.

Comment: Also, the assembly files generated by IDA don't contain line numbers or the raw binary instructions.

Comment: @3pidemix  that is wrong statement  do  options - > general opcode bytes 15  then run this script and take a look auto foo;
foo = fopen("c:\\foo.asm" , "wb");
if(foo == 0) {Message("file open failed"); return 0;}
GenerateFile(3,foo,0x1012803,0x1012824,16);
fclose(foo);    :\>grep .text c:\foo.asm
00000004 ContextRecord   dd ?  ; offset
.text:01012803
.text:01012803  loc_1012803: ; CODE XREF: sub_10127F7+14↓j
.text:01012803 66 8B 30 mov     si, [eax]
.text:01012806 40       inc     eax
.text:01012807 40       inc     eax

Comment: @blabb Looks to me like you're dumping IDA's listing, and not assembly.  The listing is what you see displayed when you view the disassembly in IDA's text view.  GenerateFile() can generate an actual assembly file - check out the OFILE_* symbols (first argument to GenerateFile()).  If you change that arg to 4, it will generate a .asm file, just like (as mentioned by Rad Lexus above) File->Produce File->Create ASM File... does.

Comment: @3pidemix yes it is listing and not assemble able asm file  and OP inherted a listing  i was just pointing you out that the bequeather left him a listing

Comment: Correct - the semantics of his question are a bit misleading, which is what I was attempting to rectify :)

Comment: Okay I will fix this. Thank you for clearify things

Comment: @3pidemix So it woult be possible to read in the listings and convert them with the help of IDAPython full automatically (as a batch job for a large number of files) ?

Comment: Without access to the source .idb files that generated the listings, your best bet is probably @blabb's solution.  Even with the .idb files, I'm pretty sure the free version of IDA doesn't come with IDAPython support so you'd be stuck with IDC.  In that case, you may be able to just dump actual assembly vs. listing with the script posted above.